# Why does SSH think I still have a 'known_hosts2' file?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, known-hosts

While trying to clean up my SSH config and key files on my iMac (macOS Monterey 12.1), I tried to SSH using the verbose flag (-v). This generated output including the following lines:

```
...
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/clint/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
...
```

I know that I tried to create a backup of my known_hosts file (and called it "known_hosts2") but I've since deleted it.

Does anyone know how can I find out why SSH still references (and thinks I have) an old file called 'known_hosts2'?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `locate known_hosts`?

Comment: I tried it and it only found a Ruby file in Homebrew (known_hosts.rb). I'll read up on using 'locate' but this has made me realize that my original title for this post "How can I find all known_hosts files?" is misleading. What I really want to do is find out why SSH thinks I still have a file named 'known_hosts2'. I will re-title this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default configuration for ssh in openssh has `UserKnownHostsFile` set to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and. `~/.ssh/known_hosts2`. The config is similar for `GlobalKnownHostsFile` except it looks for these files in `/etc/ssh` as seen in the man page (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html). So  openssh ssh checks those 4 files by default which is what you see in `ssh -v`.

I'm not sure how much the configuration (and implementation) of MacOS SSH differs from openssh default, but at least in this case they seem to behave the same.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer. I think it was just a coincidence that I backed up the 'known_hosts' file and called the backup 'known_hosts2'. This is also the name of the SSH2 file that SSH is looking for in the SSH -v output that I saw.

Answer (score 1):

To fix `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory`, you can add a file for `UserKnownHostsFile` to your SSH config, such as:

```
UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

To fix `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory`, you can add a file for `GlobalKnownHostsFile` to your SSH config, such as:

```
GlobalKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```